# How to limit the number of clicks in mouse Clicked Event in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i have done a mouse click event for jcombobox but how to limit it to only one click....As as click again and again the combobox value keeps increasing.

Comment: Can you also post what you have done so far? Looks like you might need a different Swing component or just try to manage the state "as of how many clicks you need" for that one in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't limit a click, but you can limit the number of clicks that *are registered*. Just set a global boolean called `firstClicked` with an initial value of **false**, and then add a listener. Inside the listener, add this:

```
if(!firstClicked) {
    // Exceute code (increase value)
    firstClicked = true;
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

When the JComboBox is clicked for the first time, set the variable to **true**, and execute your code. Then when it is clicked again, nothing will happen.